# Map comma in select mode to exit select mode, enter insert mode, append a comma

Tags: vimrc, macvim, plugin-ultisnips, select-mode

Is it possible to remap comma in select mode to exit select mode, enter insert mode, [optionally: go the end of the last selection (which the cursor seems to be for ultisnips)] and append a comma? This can be very useful while using a ultisnips snippet below to quickly add new items to a `opt=val` type argument list: new `,opt1=val1,opt2=val2,opt3=val3`

```
snippet , "add one more item" i
,${1:option}=${2:value}
endsnippet
```

I tried something like this:

`smap , <Esc><Esc>a,`

but it doesn't do that, and ends up deleting the last selection.

Answer (score 1):

You must use `snoremap` as your mappings' RHS contains LHS. And this is a good habit anyway.

> exit select mode, enter insert mode, [optionally: go the end of the last selection (which the cursor seems to be for ultisnips)] and append a comma?

For simplicity, let's assume that `:h 'selection'` is inclusive. Then we have

```
snoremap , <Esc>g`>a,
```

Comment: Thanks, actually I needed to add this ``let g:UltiSnipsRemoveSelectModeMappings = 0`` to my ``.vimrc`` as ultinips plugin overwrites users select mode mappings. There is apparently a way to disable only few mappings, though I didn't try that.